# Class 'App\Libs\Emotes' not found (Laravel & Blade)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm currently having an Issue with Laravel (5), Its been a long time since I haven't touched laravel since the early versions of 4, and as soon as Laravel 5 was released I boarded the train and thought I would have a go with it, specifically with a Emote phraser.

Basically the over-all issue I'm having is `Class "App\Libs\Emote is not found"` although I think I've registered the alias correctly for us, but someone could prove me wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel</title>

        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%;
                display: table;
                font-weight: 100;
                font-family: 'Lato';
            }

            .container {
                text-align: center;
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            .content {
                text-align: center;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .title {
                font-size: 96px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            {{
                Emote::PhraseEmote()
            }}
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title">(flag:gb) (flag:us)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


Class;

<?php
namespace Libs\Emotes;

class Emotes {

    public static function PhraseEmote($value) {
        $config = Config::get('emotes');

        $smileys = $config['render_phrase'];

        foreach($emotes as $key => $val) {
            //$value = str_replace($key, '<img src="' . $config['path'] . $smileys[$key][0] . '" width="' . $smileys[$key][1] . '" height="' . $smileys[$key][2] . '" alt="' . $smileys[$key][3] . '" style="border:0;" />', $value);
            $value = str_replace($key, $emotes[$key][0], $value);
        }

        return $value;
    }
}
?>

Config;

<?php
return array(
    'render_phrase'    => array(
        '(flag:gb)' => array('<i class="gb flag" data-content="United Kingdom" data-variation="tiny"></i>'),
        '(flag:us)' => array('<i class="us flag" data-content="United States" data-variation="tiny"></i>'),
        //'(flag:CN_Code)' => array('<i class="CN_CODE flag" data-content="United States" data-variation="tiny"></i>'),
    )
);
```

Comment: Try changing to `namespace App\Libs;`.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your folder structure I think this might help.

The name space is the base directory (path) of the class. So

`namespace App\Libs\EmoteLib`

Since your class does not extend any class you are good to go now.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Could you be a little more clear on exactly what you mean.

Comment: Using the namespace App\Libs\Emotes means that in the app directory there is a libs directory containing an emotes class or something like that. But in laravel5 we specify the namespace to be the controllers folder, that is what is specified above and then we use or classes. so \Emotes;

Comment: I'm still confused about what you mean; Here's a picture to reference my structure: http://prntscr.com/7nqnux

Comment: Hey TheOnlyDroid, I have edited my answer on your folder structures basics. One thing is that change the file name from `emotes.php` to `Emotes.php` so that it corresponds to the same case as the class itself. I think this should work.

Comment: Hey Gideon, Is way too warm for me to concentrate correctly (as it stand); There is one bit of information that I forgot to give you and thats the 'App' config with the Alias in it. 

App Config: http://prntscr.com/7nsjjt
New Error: http://prntscr.com/7nsju7

Sorry in advance if this is taking more time than it should.

Comment: Hi Gideon, I would like to thank you for all the help that you've given me, its really given me allot of insight into Custom Classes and name-spaces in Laravel; I manged to fix the issue that I previously stated, it was due to the double \Emotes that I didn't even realize that I had done.

Comment: You are welcome onlyDroid but the best way to say thank you here is to check the appropriate answer that solved your problem.